# How can I rewrite this code without while loop?

Tags: javascript, optimization

> He drops the ball out of the window. The ball bounces (for example), to two-thirds of its height (a `bounce` of 0.66).
>
> His mother looks out of a window 1.5 meters from the ground.
>
> How many times will the mother see the ball pass in front of her window (including when it's falling and bouncing?

Here is my solution:

```js
function bouncingBall(h, bounce, window) {
  let count = 0;
  if (h < 0 || bounce <= 0 || window >= h) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    count += 2
  }

  let jump = h * bounce

  while (jump > window) {
    jump *= bounce
    count += 2;
  }
  return count - 1;
}

console.log(bouncingBall(3.0, 0.66, 1.5)) //3
```

The result I got is correct, but apparently, it's not efficient enough, because it takes some time to run everything. Any suggestions on how could I make it "better"?

Comment: now you have the right answer, why don't you math it out?

Comment: That "_some time_" is far less than a millisecond, why to bother?

Answer (score 1):

You need to figure out `x`, the number of times the ball needs to bounce for its peak to be below the window:

```
h * (bounce ** x) = window
```

Solving for `x`, we get

```
bounce ** x = window / h
ln(bounce ** x) = ln(window / h)
x * ln(bounce) = ln(window / h)
x = ln(window / h) / ln(bounce)
```

This will give you the number of bounces after which the peak will be below the window. Multiply by 2 (because the ball comes up and comes back down, passing the window twice), and add 1 if, the first time, the ball is dropped from higher than the window:

```js
function bouncingBall(h, bounce, window) {
  const bounces = Math.floor(Math.log(window / h) / Math.log(bounce));
  return bounces * 2 + (h > window ? 1 : 0);
}

console.log(bouncingBall(3.0, 0.66, 1.5))
```